# How to set font size for tinyMCE editor?

Tags: css, tinymce-4

I want to set font size of content inside tinyMCE editor to 16px.

```
<style>
#TinyMCE{font-size:16px;}
</style>
<textarea id="TinyMCE" name="body"></textarea>
```

This didn't work. How to do that?

Comment: Did you try !important? `#TinyMCE{font-size:16px !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
   font-size: 16px;
}

tinyMCE.init({
    content_css: "http://url/editor.css"
```